# the right pdf converter

Tags: pdf, windows-8, powerpoint

I know there is another thread for asking it but adobe reader didn't work out for me.
actually, I am working out on an electronic project. and I need to copy few formulae directly from pdf to my MS word and MS powerpoint. 
Adobe is not too good at it. most symbols I copy from the reader to MS come in the form of small rectangular boxes- an indication it failed to convert them.
please do suggest me some good tool in this regard that could copy mathematical symbols directly from the pdf to the MS word and ppt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even I had suffered the same. adobe pdf reader does fail to copy the symbols to doc. i used [Nitro](https://www.gonitro.com/) later. worked ok but not satisfying yet.
Then i used [Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html). met my needs pretty well.
been using it for past 3 years.
it easily converted the entire pdf to .doc. saved much of my labor. 
mathematical symbols untampered.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Jennifer! Could you please [edit] your post and include the URL for Sumatra, so readers of your answer can easily find it?